# Swap function with pointers only work with some data types and not others

Tags: c, pointers, types

I wanted to implement a swap function that works with all data types. I now know that this is not easily possible without malloc etc. But my real confusion is about why the following functions work with different data types:

```
//short int unsigned long
void swapInt(char* a, char* b)
{
   char tmp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = tmp;
}

//double long
void swapDouble(void **pptr1, void **pptr2) 
{   
   void *temp1 = *pptr1; 

   *pptr1 = *pptr2;        
   *pptr2 = temp1;
}

//float
void swapFloat(void *a, void *b){
   int aux; 
   aux = *(int*)(a);//
   *(int*)(a) = *(int*)(b); 
   *(int*)(b) = aux; 
}

int main()
{
   #define SIZE 5
   int array[SIZE]={1,2,2,2,5};
   
   printf("before:\n ");
   for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
       printf("%d ", array[i]);
           
   swapInt(&array[0], &array[4]);  
   printf("\n");
   
   printf("after:\n ");    
   for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
       printf("%d ", array[i]);
       
   return 0;
}
```

The output of the main as it is shown in the code block was:
before:
1 2 2 2 5
after:
5 2 2 2 1

If I change the array to double or float its:
before:
1.000000 2.000000 2.000000 2.000000 5.000000
after:
1.000000 2.000000 2.000000 2.000000 5.000000

Testing it with the other functions, it still gives different results for different data types.
Please explain this to me, it's really frustrating.

EDIT:
I used this online compiler https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler
the warnings I get are following:
main.c:37:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘swapInt’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
main.c:4:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
main.c:37:23: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘swapInt’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
main.c:4:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
And it works, or I wouldn't have said it works. I tried different functions I found on stack overflow and now I'm confused why they work or seem to work.

Comment: float and int may not be the same size or have the same memory alignment.  In order for your swap to work correctly, you'll need to pass a size_t paramter for the size of the data type, and copy byte for byte (char or unsigned char).

Comment: Why do your swap functions take `char *` arguments for int, `void **` for double, and `void *` for float? First step is to fix those to be `void swapInt(int *a, int *b)` and similar. The way it is now, it doesn't work even for ints, try for example to set the first element of `array` to `-1` instead of `1`.

Comment: Don't you get compiler warnings? If so - fix them. If not - make sure to increase the compilers warning level.

Comment: @dxiv sounds obvious tiping it but for int it should be void swapInt(int *a, int *b), for double void swapDouble(double*a, double*b) etc?

Comment: @vokitori No, both arguments *have* to be pointers, so `void swapInt(int *a, int *b)`.

Comment: @dxiv yes of course, not able to type today apparently. Okay, it works now thank you, but my questions why all those weird functions I had work is still not solved. Especially why swapDouble gave me the right result only for double?

Comment: @vokitori All three posted functons have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) so there is no point to try and second-guess why something in particular happened. If you changed the compile from 64-bit to 32-bit, for example, you would be getting different results.

Comment: @dxiv Okay thank you, I'll also take undefined behavior as an answer, never said I wouldn't

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't even work for `int` variables except possibly on systems where `sizeof int` is 1. Try swapping 1 and 258. I expect that you'll end up with 2 and 257 (though that is by no means something you can rely on).

You need to copy the right number of bytes, and you must do so in a way that doesn't violate alignment rules.

You can use the following:

```
void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size) {
   char buf[size];
   memmove(buf, a, size);
   memmove(a, b, size);
   memmove(b, buf, size);
}
```

Example invocation:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 258;
printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
swap(&a, &b, sizeof a);
printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
```